# Making an alternating background (with 2 image

Tags: html, css

I’m new to coding, but I’m learning HTML. I started my website and I’m learning with a course I’m HTML and some css by learning as I go. What I want to do is change my background images to this ex. 
(Row 1) IMG1 IMG2 IMG1 IMG2 (etc.) (Row 2)
IMG2 IMG1 IMG2 IMG1 (etc.) I want them to alternate left to right and top to bottom.
I’m not sure how to do this
So far I have this but I want a bit more pattern to it:
http://idk.freetzi.com/idk/idk.html#

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code and try to use this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand your question and there're several ways to alternate images as your request.

1. Update the background animated GIF from your link. You can achieve this by image editor such as Photoshop. This is easiest way for beginners.
2. Prepare several separated images (in your case: IMG 1, IMG2 ...etc), build some DIV blocks / flexbox in desired order, so you can set different background images instead of a single one (body background image).
3. If you want to animate images, do it in the same way as point 2 but use IMG tag instead of background-image, then you can use CSS3 animation to animate them.

There're always alternative ways to achieve the same result, I suggest you to post your code and upload an image of the desired result to make your question easier to understand.

Hope this help.